# Debugging Rails Spree. Might be database related

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

My problem is only remote.

My problem is that in the States Controller, a **Country** does not exist in the database.

But on remote if I `rails c`, Country works. Country's relationship with States works. Vice versa, and they both have plenty of information on both.

**The battlefield (SFW):**

```
class Admin::StatesController < Admin::ResourceController
  #belongs_to :country
  # ^^ This default line with spree will break the app because once this controller is touched, Country is nil in this part of the app.
  before_filter :load_data, :except => [:index]

  def index
    #@country = Country.first
    #@country ||= Country.find_by_iso("US")
    # ^ Does not work because no countries are in the database from the app. Even though countries are accessible in rails console.

    @trip = "yes"
    @users = User.all
    @countries = Country.all
    # ^^ Country as a class exists but it is not populated in this part of the app.
```

So with this controller code, if I throw this in my view, I can see :

1. The value of `@trip`. That means the controller can send data.
2. The value of @users. That means the database is working. I can list through all the users and their emails
3. *I do not see a single country listed*. None of them appear. But again, if I rails c into the console and try this, it works fine. There's 51 states for the United States. And all of them call back to their country in perfect patriotic matrimony.

Can anyone make heads or tails out of what is going on here?

Comment: I would suggest that stabbing yourself with a fork is more painful, (and that the scars are more longer lasting) than debugging spree, and so your title is factually incorrect. Are you sure that is everything in that controller? What version of Spree is this?

Comment: Case in point. Updated title.

Comment: Trip, can't help but notice that your update has forked these comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that you're running the console in development mode and your app in release mode.Try

```
rails c production
```

I'd wager your countries don't exist in the production database.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU GOOD SIR JEFF PAQUETTE!

Answer (score 2):

I'd classify this answer as no better than 'partial and likely.'  Consider posting your view code to help clarify your question.  Either way, perhaps this debugging advice may get you to your answer.

Could it be you are seeing behavior related to two different Rails environments?  Try showing `Rails.env` in both cases then take a look at your config/database.yml file. In that file, you may see different databases for each of your project's Rails environments.  The differing environments may have names like, "test', 'production', and 'development.'  You may note that the listed databases connected to for each environment are different.  If you ensure '`countries`' (and the other relevant tables) is populated in the databases for the environment used by 'rails c' and by your application, then the behavior should be similar.

More on Rails.env [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Rails/env/class).

Comment: YES! THANK YOU GOOD SIR PERRY HORWHICH!